# How to get rid of this error mismatched input 'line' expecting <EOF>(line 1, pos 17) in spark-sql

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

```sql
select case 
when line = 'KEY' 
  then case 
when length(pop)>0 and pop not rlike '^[0-9]+@.*' 
  then '' 
else case 
  when pop rlike '^[0-9]+@.*' 
    then regexp_extract(pop, '^[^@]+', 0) end 
  else '' end as pop from input
```

The above code throughs the error "mismatched input 'line' expecting (line 1, pos 17)"

can anyone help me with this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 CASE clause but only 2 END statements, you missed one more END keyword.
And one CASE clause can have only one ELSE clause.

Below modified query should work for you.

```
SELECT
      CASE
             WHEN line = 'KEY' THEN
                    CASE
                           WHEN Length(pop)>0
                           AND    pop NOT rlike '^[0-9]+@.*' THEN ''
                           ELSE
                                  CASE
                                         WHEN pop rlike '^[0-9]+@.*' THEN regexp_extract(pop, '^[^@]+', 0)
                                         ELSE ''
                                  END
                    END
              ELSE ''
       END as pop
             FROM   input
```

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it becomes tricky when writing nested "case" statements, use a editor

like notepad++ (Language -> sql) and check if the case/end are balanced.

[image]

And when you select "end" there are only 2.

[image]

Note that "else" is optional.

From the picture it is clear that an "end" statement is missing.
Try to align each case/end statement on the same vertical ruler using tabs/spaces.
Now you can identify the issue easily.

Check this.

[image]